# How to access AudioStream amplitude data for VU Meter

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

Im doing a music player that is based on this [one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202978%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) using the BackgroundAudioPlayer I’m trying to extend and add a VU meter.

While searching i’ve seen some examples but they were using the microphone input to get the data (not from a track that is currently playing) then using a graphic with a rectangle mask to show/hide as the amplitude changes up or down, i’ve been looking through the documentation and forums but did not find anything similar to what I’m trying to do.

My question is how can i access the amplitude data from that audio stream (currently playing) to calculate the data for the VU meter?
This would only be active when App was in foreground as there would be no point in having it running if it wasn’t being displayed.

If anyone has any ideas on how to do this, share some sample code or point me to an example i would appreciate it.

PS I edited my question couse i realised i had not been clear enough before, thanks @venerik for pointing it out and @Hans passant for the gauges links.

Thanks,
Bob

Comment: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8c83d3c2-40be-476a-827e-40f65aac23bb

Comment: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/007e14ba-98b8-48a2-9028-54361efee063

Comment: http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2013/11/05/A-Modern-UI-radial-gauge-control-for-Windows-Phone-8-apps.aspx

Comment: wow 30+ views and not a single answer...
Is it possible that with so many brains up in here, nobody can help me out!?
It seemed like such a simple thing to do (at least in my mind).